# Extending from multiple classes in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance, composition

i know java doesn't support multiple inheritance. I have 3 concrete base classes say A,B and C. I want to reuse all the utility methods in A,B & C in a single class D.I can not use composition as classes A,B and C are not to be played with.Please give me a way out.

Thanks and Regards,
Saurabh

Comment: Use interfaces instead.

Comment: You may look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917190/multiple-inheritance-in-java

Comment: Using inheritance just because you want to use methods from some class is a bad idea - that's not what inheritance is meant for.

Comment: Inheritance and composition are the ways provided by OO for extending the functionality. I dont understand what you mean by cannot play with A,B and C. You can use them as data members in a different class, say D or E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use Facade pattern

[Facade http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC400938.png](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC400938.png)

As for your example:

- SubsystemA is your class A
- SubsystemB is your class B
- SubsystemC is your class C
- Facade is your D class, where you can do whatever you want.

I think you can use composition in this way because it doesn't break encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using multiple interfaces is possible (and very common).

If order to use multiple extended classes, you need to use:

`A extends B`, `B extends C` and `D extends A` but is not always possible.

Consider using [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) instead of multiple inheritances.

Comment: Except B will have access to A when it shouldn't.

Comment: And as OP stated, A B and C are not to be changed.